# Create a JS "If" statement with defined/undefined variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have been getting tossed around trying to figure this out. I am trying to create an IF statement. Here is the example:

```
if (vectorLayer.features.length == 0 || typeof vectorLayer =='undefined') {DO STUFF}
```

However, I get an error bc if vectorLayer does not exist, the first part of the statement cannot be read. I am trying to make this action happen if either the object does not exist OR if it exists but contains no features. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Check for vector layer being undefined _before_ checking its features. If it is undefined then the || statement will short circuit and not even execute the next statement.

Comment: Geez I started typing my answer then "There are 83 new answers and they're all the same as yours!" popped up..

Comment: BTW. individual parts of condition are being evaluated from left to right ... order matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, the check for undefined comes first so it wont do the rest of the condition if vectorLayer isn't defined.

```
if (vectorLayer == undefined || vectorLayer.features.length == 0) {DO STUFF}
```

Comment: wow- of course.. It's always the simplest things I miss. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanFoster - `===` checks for both value and type, which can lead to inconsistent behavior. **Never** check undefined with `===` because if a variable is declared but not instantiated it will be set to `null` which does not `===` undefined even though any attempted access will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Flip the conditional statement around. The right side of the `||` won't get evaluated if the left side is true, because the value of the right side makes no difference to the truthiness of the whole expression if the left side is true. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
if (typeof vectorLayer =='undefined' || vectorLayer.features.length == 0) {
    // DO STUFF...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!vectorLayer || !vectorLayer.features.length) {DO STUFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (typeof vectorLayer !== 'undefined' && vectorLayer.features.length == 0) {
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: If you're going to reverse the `if` statement like that, you need to check if the length is *not* 0 (using `!=`. Otherwise, the IF statement will not correspond to the original (because the conditions do not match the original `if` statement).

Comment: @Caleb531 I'm not sure what you mean here. I didn't negate the if statement, I negated the first one only. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Never mind what I said. I simply misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish with your code.

When I say "negating" (which is probably not the right word), I mean taking an `if` statement, and making the operators opposite. So, the opposite of `a == true && b == false` would be `a != false || b != true`. You might use that trick when rearranging your `if` statements, but it's not relevant here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the left side of an OR operator (`||`) is evaluated first. Therefore, by switching the placement of the two conditions, the `typeof` check will catch the undefined variable before JavaScript tries to retrieve some property of the object.

```
if (typeof vectorLayer === 'undefined' || vectorLayer.features.length === 0 ) {
    // DO STUFF
}
```

However, rather than using the `typeof` operator, you can more easily check if a variable is `udefined` using `===`:

```
vectorLayer === undefined
```